# Multi Connections to DB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a project where at pick times the site will get 1000 calls per secs this calls need to be saved in the DB ( MS-SQL DB )  .

What is the best practice to manage this large scale connections.

I am using .net C# .
Currently building this as a site that get all the calls in post way.

Thanks For your answers.

Comment: what do you want to save in the db?

Comment: i have a unique ID and JSON value.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience the fastest way to insert a large amount of data is to use a `GUID` as `PK`. If you use an autoincrement the sql will write the rows one by one to get the next ID.
But if there is a `GUID`, the server will write all your data at the "same" time.

Depending on the ressources of your production machine there are several approaches:

1fst: Store all the requests in one big list and your application writes all the requests synchronously into your database. Pro: pretty easy to code, Con: could be a real bottleneck

2nd: Store all the requests in one big list and your application starts a thread for every 1000 requests that you received, these threads write the data into your database asynchronously. Pro: Should be faster, Con: hard to code and hard to maintain.

3rd: Store the request inside the memory of the server and write the data into the database when the application is not busy.